# Validation schema in JPA

Tags: java, validation, openjpa

I use JPA 1.0 version OPENJPA implementation.

I want compare tables in database with my JPA entities. I added the following property to `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="validate" />
```

If there is a field in my entity but there is no such column in the database then JPA warns that schema is not valid.
But if there is some column in the table but it is not mapped to any field in the entity then JPA ignores it.

How can I prompt JPA to warn me in this case?

Comment: You want to check your Java object for missing columns from the database? So, like read the database table and check if it is mapped "somewhere" in your JPA entities?

Comment: yes it is exactly what I want.

Comment: Don't think if it's even possible. You don't need to map all columns to your Java objects.

Answer (score 0):

Well standard JPA 1.0 doesn't support such a feature, and from what I can see not even OpenJPa non standard features will help you with this.